# Android: how to store resources that may be updated at runtime

Tags: android, configuration, resources, updates

What is the best way to store sound files (ogg) that are distributed with the app and updated at runtime?

I am developing an app that includes a default set of sounds as resources (res/raw/*.ogg). These work fine for the defaults but I want the user to be able to update the set of sounds with recorded sounds and downloads from the Internet. The problem is that the resources are read-only and, I think, assets are also read-only. I don't know how to include files in the project so they can be updated at runtime.

I can have the defaults as resources and files added at runtime on internal storage or SD Card, but I would prefer to have all the files in one place with a single interface for accessing them. Is there a way to include files in the project so they are written to internal storage or SD Card when the app is installed? Or is there a better place to put the files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your files in `/asset` directory when packaging the .apk file. At runtime copy those files in application's internal storage `/data/data/<application_package_name>/files` (If files are not to much sized, It useful when device has no external storage included). Also update the files in same location..

Comment: That's not a bad solution, except for the duplication of the files: in resources and internal storage. Can they be deleted from /assets after the copy somehow?

Comment: No from /asset you can't delete those files. From internal storage you can. Also its better to put only update files on internal storage and use updated files from that. So you don't ahve a duplicate sopies for files in both place.