# Android: assets alternative

Tags: java, android

I'm using **assets** as standard **icons storage** but now I have request that these icons should be **updated** for some cases. I know that I can't touch assets, so do you have any suggestions where to store them?? These files should be **pre-installed** and **updated** for some cases. From start I've been thinking about **Internal Storage** but now I have some doubts. What do you think???

Comment: Look at my answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151764/android-how-to-store-resources-that-may-be-updated-at-runtime/11151850#11151850

Comment: So I'll have to check each time is file on Internal Storage, and if not, check Assets :(

Comment: Why? Whenever you found update on your file store updated file in internal storage then, when you have to access that file just load it from internal storage. Else load it from /asset..

Comment: Right, I immediately thought on keeping only changed files in storage to save space. Remnants of Java Mobile programming....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution to this problem was to put current available images in assets. App checks is there anything new every time user logs in, if yes places new images in /data/../images folder. When  icons are required, I first check assets and then the storage. In new app releases I include the new icons in the assets folder.